# Problems while trying to add an xml file to Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

Am facing an issue with Alfresco and honestly am not expert with this type of technology:
the idea is to add an xml file under a folder
the code is like that:

```
//with the static values are:
public static final String SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_NAME = "suspendreDesuspendre";
private static final String SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/xml";
private static final String SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
private static final ContentFormat SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_FORMAT = new ContentFormat(SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_TYPE,SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_ENCODING);

private static final byte[] SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_INITIAL_BYTES = "<?xml //version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><suspendreDesuspendre></suspendreDesuspendre>".getBytes();
@Override
public void createOrUpdateHisSuspendre(ContractBean contractbean,SuspendreDesuspendreEntree suspendreDesuspendreEntree) throws Exception
{
 String parentUuid=contractbean.getUuid();
 contractDAO.createAlfrescoContent(parentUuid, SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_NAME,      SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_INITIAL_BYTES, SUSPENDRE_DESUSPENDRE_CONTENT_FORMAT);
}

public Reference createAlfrescoContent(String folderUuid, String contentName,byte[] contentBytes,ContentFormat contentFormat)throws RepositoryFault, RemoteException {
       ParentReference parentReference = new ParentReference(new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore"), folderUuid, null, Constants.ASSOC_CONTAINS, "{" + Constants.NAMESPACE_CONTENT_MODEL + "}" + contentName);
       NamedValue[] properties = new NamedValue[]{Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_NAME, contentName)};
       CMLCreate create = new CMLCreate("1", parentReference, null, null, null,
                Constants.TYPE_CONTENT, properties);
       CML cml = new CML();
       cml.setCreate(new CMLCreate[]{create});
       UpdateResult[] result = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml);     

        Reference newContentNode = result[0].getDestination();
        Content content = WebServiceFactory.getContentService().write(newContentNode, Constants.PROP_CONTENT, contentBytes, contentFormat);

        return content.getNode();
    }
```

the error is:

```
The association source type is incorrect:
Source Node: workspace://SpacesStore/d4ffbff4-6bd6-4945-948e-2c16c1990cb9
Association: Association[ class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder], name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source role=null, target role=null]
Required Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder
Actual Source Type: {com.genia.cnas.alfresco.model}contratDefenseur
```

Comment: Where's the bit of code that talks to the NodeService? We need to see what you're passing to that to understand what you're doing wrong

Comment: code added @Gagravarr

Comment: Does your source type, {com.genia.cnas.alfresco.model}contratDefenseur, inherit from cm:folder?